# Magmi Category Description Import

Tags: magento, categories, magmi

i try to find any information in the Magmi Wiki pages, but still nothing help to solve some problem. I succesfully imported about 3000 SKUs with Category. But for SEO I nedd to put into all Category Descriptions. My question is that possible to import Category Description task with Magmi? If yes, which rows I must define in the flat files?

For all your questions thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Basically Magmi do not have that function, you can follow up magento modules page, if will be module wit that function released:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/files/magmi-0.7/plugins/packages/

Answer (score 1):

Magmi will only import products.  There are add on functions that will create categories and attributes on the fly, but that's as far as it will go on non-product items.

For mass updates to category information, if you look around you should be able to find extensions in Magento Connect that may do the trick or you could write your own import based on this [Sonassi example](https://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-kb/magento-batch-update-category-quick-script/).

Good Luck